# Biztalk persistence - how to track what objects and messages are persisted

Tags: size, profiling, persistence, biztalk

I have a problem with an application running in Biztalk. It is processing a lot of data and making a lot of calls to SAP (thousands of calls per one input file). The problem is that traffic to SQL server is 10x bigger than to SAP.

I suspect there are some messages being persisted to database  by Biztalk, that could be avoided or are not needed at that stage.

To provide some numbers, processing of 3 files gives me around 5-6 persistence point /sec and 1MB/s traffic to SQL server.

Is there any way to see, what is persisted to database and size of each message/object?

Comment: Is this causing an actual problem or is it just something you have observed?

Comment: Each send shape is taking around 170-200ms (time between send start and send finish) even for 1kB messages. Each scope end also takes around 100ms. If my calculations are correct, the delay caused by persistence takes around 50-70% of the whole processing time. Incoming messages are XML and can be as big as 3MB, so i believe there is some incorrect handling of these messages and i am looking for some way to verify it and optimize.

Answer (score 1):

The Orchestration Engine will Persist all in-scope variables at each Persistence Point.

While there is no way to change that behavior, you can mitigate the amount of persisted date by:

1. Keeping Message Variables scoped at the lowest level possible, such as a Scope Shape instead of Global (at the Orchestration level).
2. Reducing the number of Persistence Points.

Unfortunately, you may find the two at odds since adding a Scope may create a new Persistence Point.

Persistence points are listed here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sanket/archive/2006/11/12/understanding-persistence-points-in-biztalk-orchestration.aspx

However, keep in mind that what you're observing is the intended behavior of the product.  Just because the Send Shape might spend 200ms persisting is not a problem in itself.  Unless you're severely resource constrained and this is causing a measurable impact on SLA's, I wouldn't think twice about it.

Comment: Hi. TO be more specific, i have a "manager" orchestration, which analyzes the initial input message and forwards this message to sub orchestrations (calls). Inside each specialized orchestration, part of the input message is processed. What i was wondering was if the original input message is also persisted inside the called orchestration, or just local variables and messages (declared within orchestration + input parameters) are persisted. I already optimized it by moving all messages to most inner scopes, but still the process is too slow in my opinion :)

Comment: A Call Orchestration Shape does not create a Persistence Point, however, if there are Persistence Points in the called Orchestration, anything in the calling Orchestration will persist.  Optimization is an interesting exercise but again, I wouldn't have even looked at this.  I'd bet a whole $1 the bottleneck in any of those operations is SAP.